# Did Qrow cut Winter?

Tags: rwby, fan-theory

There is a picture [on Imgur](https://m.imgur.com/a/7dgVCDL)  where someone is saying that Qrow didn't put that cut on Winter but she was battling him when the cut was spotted:

[image: Winter with a cut on her shoulder]

So what? Had it been there or did Qrow cut Winter?

Comment: To close-voters: I don't see why this was voted as primarily opinion-based. Even if it had not been an edited picture (which it is), there could still have been an answer along the lines of "yeah character X cut her in episode Y" or "no, she always had that scar". Voted to leave open.

Comment: But...doesn't the fact that the picture was entirely made up rob the entire question of its very premise? No picture, no question. Unless I misundestood and that *cut* is genuinely there at a later/earlier point and is itself not part of the whole con.

Comment: @TARS I'm obviously biaised in this thread (since I was the one who answered), but from where I stand, a question that goes "We have `statement X`. Does that mean `implication Y`?" can legitimately be answered by "`statement X` being a false premise - and here's the evidence -,  `implication Y` did not happen". In-context, no, Qrow did not cut Winter, because no one cut Winter to begin with. (grammatically at least, it does answer "Did Qrow cut Winter?")

Comment: Hmm, makes sense too, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Qrow did not cut Winter, *because no one cut Winter to begin with*.

Someone needs to get better at Photoshopping, because in this picture from [Volume 3, chapter 3](https://youtu.be/vCO2mw4SlDM?t=530) there clearly is no cut on Winter's shoulder.

[image: Winter without a cut]

Comment: So the photo on Imgur is edited?

Comment: @Connor well, the cut does not appear in the Rooster Teeth version of the episode so I'm inclined to say it is, yes.

Comment: @Connor in three seconds with Paint, I can sketch [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpE36.png) which is kind of close to what the Imgur photo looks like, so someone can edit the Imgur one if they take a bit more time (five minutes, tops).

Comment: @Connor the timestamp for that shot is linked in the answer above. Definitely edited :) no problem in asking though! (and even less problem in [accepting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you, but know that it's not mandatory, I'm just giving you a friendly nudge!)

Comment: You did help thanks.